# binning series and returning innerbin sums not occurences as histogram

Tags: python, pandas

I hope title can clarify well the situation.

Lets say I have a series with the first 12 elements as shown below:

[image]

I'd like to have a histogram with specified bins, but I don't want to have number of occurences under bins. Instead I want a sum of the values under the bins. That is for this particular 12 elements, it should be in the form:

- for 51-60 bin: 53+53+55+58+59 not 5
- for 71-80 bin: 71+72+72 not 3
- for 101-110 bin : 102+102 not 2
- for 111-120 bin : 114 not 1
- for other bins just 0.

I used `cumsum` but that was not the thing I'm looking for. For bins, I used `np.arange(0,130,10)` with `pd.cut`.

A similar questing is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915273/binning-and-summing-of-time-spent-in-bins) but I couldn't tricked that into my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the intervals defined by `pd.cut` and then sum the actual values:

```
s = pd.Series([114, 102, 102, 72, 72, 71, 59, 58, 58, 55, 53, 53])

s.groupby(pd.cut(s, bins=np.arange(0, 130, 10))).sum()

(0, 10]         0
(10, 20]        0
(20, 30]        0
(30, 40]        0
(40, 50]        0
(50, 60]      336
(60, 70]        0
(70, 80]      215
(80, 90]        0
(90, 100]       0
(100, 110]    204
(110, 120]    114
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Mind if I ask how to get histogram for this. I did `s.groupby(pd.cut(s, bins=np.arange(0, 130, 10))).sum().hist()` but it is not returning 0 to 130 bins. Instead it returns 0 to 350 bins.

Comment: I believe you want `s.groupby(pd.cut(s, bins=np.arange(0, 130, 10))).sum().plot.bar()`

Comment: Thats it. Actually I did `groupby` and `pd.cut` but was trying to plot with `hist`. My bad. Now it works as intended.